# Global Objects when using Mono with MonoMac

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, mono, monomac

How do I declare global instances of objects?

When using C# and .NET I would do something like this:

```
public static program {
  public static Foo MyFoo = new Foo();

  static void main() {
    MainForm = new MainForm(MyFoo);
  }
}
```

**however with Mono/MonoMac the main function calls NSApplication.Main and doesn't directly create any windows**. How would I pass an instance of MyFoo to the main window?

Note: I am trying to avoid any references to MainClass in my windows/window controllers as that creates a tight coupling. I want to reuse the window classes in other situations hence the desire for loose coupling.

Is what I want possible with MonoMac?

thanks, Andy

Answer (score 0):

Use a **[singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)** ? Your code would then look like:

```
 public class Foo {
    public static Foo Global = new Foo ();
    public Foo () { }
    // rest of Foo logic
 }

 public class Program {
   static void Main () {
      MainForm = new MainForm (Foo.Global);
   }
 }
```

Comment: You have modified the Windows version of the code, but my question is about the MonoMac version, which doesn't use MainForm as I mentioned...

Comment: I modified the only sample you gave :) but the same pattern is to be applied. Use the singleton from (any)where you need it - it will work as well on your Windows application (if you wish to change it) than it will work on your MonoMac application. The design patterns are not bound to a UI toolkit ;-)

Comment: As I mentioned in my original question - how do I pass an instance of MyFoo to the main form when it is created? If you look at MonoMac code you will see *there is no constructor called for the main window*! Also the design patterns used by Cocoa and MonoMac are NOT the same as the ones used in my trivial Windows sample. That is the whole point of my question.

Comment: Can you please post actual MonoMac code showing this? I would mark that as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: As I said **The design patterns are not bound to a UI toolkit** - each have their own *design* but the *patterns* are meant to work across them. Since you want a **global object** I suggested a **singleton**. You now have something that is **global** so you don't have to pass it to any constructor (or method). Simply use it when and where you need it, i.e. `Foo.Global` can be used inside any code. e.g. you can call `System.Text.UTF8.GetBytes(...)` anywhere without passing an `UTF8Encoding` instance everywhere.

Comment: I didn't want to create a tight coupling of classes, as I mentioned. I don't want references to globals inside the code for my window as I might want to use those windows in different situations. I solved my problem by passing the object instance to the form controller instead.

Comment: From my point of view this question is about the MonoMac MVC design pattern and how to use it rather than the Cocoa UI toolkit...